# How can I create some specific content with a cron job

Tags: drupal, cron, drupal-7

I need to create a specific content, for instance, a Page, every 15 days.

Of course that goes into some cron job.

But how can I do that? Do I need to implement the [hook_cron](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!system!system.api.php/function/hook_cron/7) at my `.module`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, hook_cron. 
You have to use some condition to prevent this happening on every cron run. A date validation or something like that.

ex:

```
function mymodule_cron() {
// Remember to add conditions.
 $node = new stdClass();
 $node->type = 'article';
 node_object_prepare($node); //important!
 $node->title    = 'Auto-node ' . date('c');
 node_save($node);
// You can optionally save some variable in the database to check the last execution time/date using variable_set()
}
```

hook_cron(), node_save(), variable_set()/get are documented in api.drupal.org so I'm not gonna explain them much.

Answer (score 0):

Or you could let [scheduler](http://dgo.to/scheduler) module handle the work of, um, scheduling publication, so all your module has to do is create this content.